# Serving static resources spring+jersey

Tags: java, spring, static, jersey

I am trying to deploy my api + react frontend and managed to serve the built index.html but i am having trouble accessing the /static/** resources shown as so:

[image]

This is my webapp structure:

[image]

(ignore the index.html over the resources dir)

With my web.xml being:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <display-name>Campus</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            ar.edu.campus.webapp.config.WebConfig,
            ar.edu.campus.webapp.security.config.WebSecurityConfig
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>jersey</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>
                ar.edu.campus.webapp.controllers,
                ar.edu.campus.webapp.security.api.exceptionmappers
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.servlet.filter.contextPath</param-name>
            <param-value>/</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>
                org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature,
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.servlet.filter.forwardOn404</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>jersey</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>index.html</location>
    </error-page>

</web-app>
```

I tried adding a resource handler over my WebConfig as such but had no result:

```
@EnableAsync
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({"ar.edu.campus.webapp.controllers", "ar.edu.campus.services", "ar.edu.campus.persistence"})
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

 ...

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
            .addResourceHandler("/static/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/spa-build/static");
        registry
            .addResourceHandler("/*.js")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/spa-build/static/js");
        registry
            .addResourceHandler("/*.css")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/spa-build/static/css");
        registry
            .addResourceHandler("/*.json")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/spa-build");
        registry
            .addResourceHandler("/*.ico")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/spa-build");
    }

   ...
}
```

I can't really tell what's going wrong, tried multiple other things already but to no avail, i still get 404 over any resource i request.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding:

```
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>../spa-client/build</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
```

under the < configuration > tag for the maven-war-plugin